# Start Appium on jenkins and wait for it to fully complete startup

Tags: jenkins, appium

I m setting up jenkins to run appium scripts. The issue I am seeing is if I run main.js to start appium the jenkins will not execute next commands and if I put appium in background next statements are executed immediately. Is there any way to start appium in background and wait for it to complete? and also once test execution complete how will I stop appium if appium process is in background?

Thanks in Advance

Shrikanth

Answer (score 0):

You can create one folder called build and put your application in same folder and create a batch file using following commands :

cd /d C"":\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules""
node appium  --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app C:\Build\Application.apk --pre-launch --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --device-name "DEVICEID" --log-no-color

Trigger this batch file from Jenkins and give wait of 20000 millisecond before running your test script.